# How Can I Add a New Value Automatically to a Dictionary in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary

I am trying to code an algorithm which it can add value  "automatically" to dictionary when user types new thing. For example...

```
my_friends = {}

friends = input("What is your friend name?")

#when i type the name, programm should add it itself. Thanks for advices.
```

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.
Specifically, repeat one or two tutorials on dictionaries.  It seems that you don't know the basics of assigning and accessing values.

Answer (score 2):

You have missed the point of a dict: with a [dict](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) you have to specify a key, for example, you could use a dict to represent your "friend":

```
friend = {
  'first_name': 'John',
  'last_name': 'Smith',
}
```

In your case, you want to use a [list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) instead, created using `[]` instead of `{}`, and then append input values to you list:

```
my_friends = []

my_friends.append(input("What is your friend name?"))
```

Comment: Great answer! However, I would add some doc links like [on lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) and [on dicts](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) and also the fact that this is a really simple question and OP should check out a python tutorial for it. Still, +1

Comment: Hi @megargayu, thanks for the feedback. I've added the links as you suggested. Regarding saying it's a simple question, I agree, but I remember that when back when I started programming I completely missed the point of a string (I was quite young and it was in CPP, so it was more complex, but still). What I'm saying is, if you miss the point of something, it can be difficult to "reset" your understanding on the topic. If you disagree with me on this, let me know, and I'll change it.

Answer (score 2):

```py
friends = {}
def addFriend():
  friends.update({input("What is your friend name?"): None})

addFriend() # asks for the friend...
addFriend() # asks for another friend...
print(friends)
```

This is an example using a function, in our case, it's named `addFriend`. The function just basically updates the `friends` dictionary using the built-in method of dictionaries `update`. `update` takes another dictionary and use that to modify the contents of the current dictionary `friends`.

So say you typed `Jessica` on the input, it will be stored in the `friends` dictionary as `{"Jessica": None}`. You can later on access this added key, value pair by doing `dict[key]` notation on the dictionary. So `friends["Jessica"]` will equal to `None` since in the function we're just adding the input string as the key with `None` as the default value for that key.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hello!, welcome to stackoverflow. While this code may answer the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how or why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Right, sorry. I thought it would be obvious. But you're right. I edited the post and tried to explain it. Hope it makes sense now.

Comment: Ah, yes. Thank you for editing your post. It looks better now.

Answer (score 1):

To add a single element in a `list`, there is the `append()` method.

If you wish a more general way to do things, as you request for an `algorithm which it can add value "automatically"`, below is a solution certainly more complicated, but also more general:

Also, since you do not seem to make use of a key, this is a `list` based solution:

```
#You define a function you can use anywhere in your code after
#The function takes the list lst and the string name as inputs
def add_name(lst,name):
    #Here is the append() part. By doing as below, you append name to the end of lst
    lst.append(name)
    #You return your modified list lst
    return lst

#Your empty list of friends
my_friends = []

#Get the friends name from input()
friends = input("What is your friend name?")

#Say your my_friends list is equal to what add_name function returns
my_friends = add_name(my_friends,friends)

#Print
print (my_friends)
```

Output:

```
#The add_name function did append the name of your friend to the empty list
['john']
```

If you want to add more than one friend:

```
def add_name(lst,name):
    lst.append(name)
    return lst

my_friends = []

#Ask for how many friends you want to add
#Input in always a string so we convert to int for needs below
number = int(input("How many?"))

#You use a for loop with number of iterations equal to number (the How many?)
for i in range(number):

    friends = input("What is your friend name?")
    
    #A new name will be appended each iteration through your function
    my_friends = add_name(my_friends,friends)

    print (my_friends)
```

For practical training on basics I'd recommend:

https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_append.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp

Comment: Way too overcomplicated - what is the use of the function that appends and then returns a list? Just use one `append` statement on the list, and it achieves the same result!

Comment: Well I imagine the "algorithm"  the OP requests for has to be a bit more general than a single append. But I may be wrong.

Comment: However, if OP wanted us to incorporate the "algorithm", then they should have asked. We can't just assume they will want to do something - we give them what they ask in the question.

Comment: "code an algorithm which it can add value "automatically" ". Well, I don't know if a single append fits that definition. Anyway he has it with the top answer, and he has some more "algorithm" way with mine. It won't hurt, as I'm not even sure he knows about this. We're here to educate, which is both giving answers and showing ways.

Comment: Btw I upvoted this, and the other answer - I think they both have merit and give the OP some guidance to get started. Both answers would benefit from some links to relevant docs.

Comment: @costaparas I agree with the docs part; and even though they might have merit, I feel like this answer can be misleading, and confusing. However, I removed my -1, because it does work.

Comment: Well I'm gonna describe more / look for some links, thanks for commenting guys

Answer (score -1):

```
my_friends = {}

my_friends["name"] = str(input("What is your friend's name?"))
```

Comment: This wont work; if you wanted to ask for another friends name, it would overwrite the previous friend's name. Also, there is no need for a dictionary in this problem; see the other answers. (No mercy for you! -1)

Comment: Hello, Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how or why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.